# seaborn line plots with date on the x axis

Tags: seaborn, line-plot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5394.png)
Hi,

I am trying to recreate some of the covid-19 charts that we have seen. I am using data from the Johns Hopkins database.

The data is arranged so that the city names are in the rows and the columns are dates. A screenshot of the csv file is attached. I want to plot line graphs in seaborn that has days in the x axis and confirmed case by city in the y axis. For some reason, I am unable to re-produce the exponential curves of the death rate.

My code is:

```
'''loading the file'''
date_columns = list(range(12,123))
df_covid_us = pd.read_csv(covid_us_file, parse_dates=date_columns)
df_covid_us = pd.read_csv(covid_us_file)

'''slicing the columns needed. Province_State and the date columns'''
df = df_covid_us.iloc[:, np.r_[6, 12:123]]
df = df[df['Province_State']=='New York']

'''using df.melt'''
df2 =df.melt(id_vars='Province_State',var_name='Date',value_name='Deaths')

'''plotting using seaborn'''[enter image description here][2]
sns.lineplot(x='Date',y='Deaths',data=df2, ci=None)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=20))
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGUXz.png)

Comment: Please always post a sample of your DataFrame as text in your question, and not as a picture. This helps people help you.

Comment: hi: how do I post a sample of my dataframe? I am using pycharm. thanks

Comment: You could do `df.head(3)` or so. I posted an answer with made-up data anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a small sample of made-up data:

```
import pandas as pd, seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.DataFrame({'Province_State':['American Samoa','Guam','Puerto Rico'],
                   '2020-01-22':[0,1,2],
                   '2020-01-23':[2,1,0]}) 

# to get dates in rows
date_columns = [c for c in df.columns.tolist() if c.endswith('/2020')]
df2 = df.melt(id_vars='Province_State',value_vars=date_columns,
              var_name='Date',value_name='Deaths')

# dates from string to datetime
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

sns.lineplot(x='Date',y='Deaths',hue='Province_State',data=df2)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1)) 

plt.show()
```

Comment: The df.melt() works. But I am getting a weird graph.  Trying to paste my code here. But it won't let me.

Comment: With the graph you can update the question with a picture of it.

Comment: Do you have a link to the data you could share? So I can see if there are these dips in the death counts, or if something else is wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_US.csv

Comment: Thanks! I looked at the data, and the graph appears accurate based on it. I wonder what is being done to the data to smooth it in the official graphs...

Comment: Hmm...I plotted it on excel. And I got the exponential that we used to seeing. On another note, does seaborn just aggregate the data -- in this case the deaths -- for the state? The data captures Covid-19 deaths by city / town. So when I do a df.melt by Province_State, at the death summed up by state? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, seaborn aggregates the data. If you wanted to graph by city within New York state you'd pass "City" or whatever the column name is to the `hue` keyword argument and you'd get a line for each city; which might be too much...